# Svelte hot reload compiles several times (2-4 times) after each save (npm run dev)

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, svelte, hot-reload

I'm using Visual Studio Code and its Terminal function on a Mac (Mini, M1) for learning svelte.

I'm doing svelte's tutorial (https://svelte.dev/tutorial/basics) and running "npm run dev" in terminal for hot reload. Everything works as it should, no errors so far.

Problem: Unfortunately, after each save, svelte is being compiled several times. This forces the browser to refresh several times which makes working uncomfortable.

Unfortunately, I don't know how and where to start troubleshooting. There are no errors.

[image: Terminal Output after saving a file - compiling several times]

Comment: Perhaps something in your operating system or editor is actually saving the file twice?